I need a list column to reference data in another column to be "checked off"
I currently use my list for project management and require a number of endorsements from various stake holders.
Currently I have a multiselect options column called "Endorsements Required" which I use to track which ones I will need to obtain, and have a Yes/no column for "All endorsements received"
Is there a way to create a "Endorsements remaining" multiselect column that copies values within the "Endorsements required" column that can be checked off separately?
I would like to have the column copy the options added within the "endorsements required" column, and update if I add any new tags within that reference column, but have the ability to mark off those options within the "endorsement remaining" column
To demonstrate, We'll call them column 1 and column 2:
Column 1 may have option 1, 2 and 3 selected. I would like column 2 to mirror this as they are added.
As I receive the required endorsements I'd like to remove option 1, and 2 from column 2. This should not affect column 1.
IF an additional option(4) is added to column 1, I would like this to be added to column 2.
Column 1 would now display option 1, 2, 3, and 4. Column 2 should only have option 3 and 4 remaining.
